# interpretation of Global Moran I values using pysal

Tags: python, autocorrelation, moran-index, pysal

I'm using pysal library (and t[his specific notebook](http://pysal.org/notebooks/viz/splot/esda_morans_viz.html)) to run spatial autocorrelation.
I have question regard the MORAN I value that I recieve.

As far as I understand, in order to be able to say something about the s**patial ditribution** (if the distiburion is dispersed, clusterd...)in given area, I **cannot only use the raw MORAN I value, but I have to get the z-score and only then I can understand the global spatial distribution**.
[image]

[image]
However, using pysal, I r**ecieve one value**, and I am not quite sure from the documentation if I can tell something from this value, for example here, I recieve 0.79 :
[image]

**Is there any way to tell something about the spatial pattern using this MORAN I value?or any other pysal function to get the z-score ?  or any way outside pysal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the last question, I generally use [GeoDA](https://geodacenter.github.io/) software to calculate the *Moran's I* (and by extension the *local indicators of spatial autocorrelation* [LISA]). This software does calculate a significance value for *Moran's I*.

On the question of the *z-score*, I am not an expert, but it seems to me that it is an indicator that makes it possible to evaluate the significance of a score, like the *Moran's I*. But I don't think it is worth using the *z-score* because the function also returns a *p-value* (well, it is an estimate made from a number of random permutations, hence the existence of a parameter `permutations` in the signature of the function).

However, if you really need the z-score, [it is specified in the documentation](https://pysal.org/esda/generated/esda.Moran.html) that the `esda.Moran` function does return its value. You should be able to access it like this :

```
moran = Moran(y, w)

# z-value of I under normality assumption
moran.z_norm

# (if permutations>0) standardized I based on permutations
moran.z_sim

# z-value of I under randomization assumption
moran.z_rand
```

The comments come from the documentation, unfortunately there are no more details about the meaning of these different values. I suppose that `z_norm` is to be used if the variable follows a normal distribution, and `z_rand` if it is not the case. As for `z_sim`, it is a value simulated by permutations, so I suppose it is this value that should be used when in doubt, **but I am really not sure.**

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for CrimeStat](https://nij.ojp.gov/topics/articles/crimestat-spatial-statistics-program-analysis-crime-incident-locations) by Ned Levine has a nice explanation of the z-score in Chapter 5.7:

[image: book extract]

The z-score is thus calculated by comparing the empirical distribution of your data to a theoretical distribution (random uniform, Gaussian, or a random permutation of your data). As noted by Atm in the accepted answer, esda calculates all three of these (z_rand, z_norm, z_sim) along with their associated p-values (p_rand, p_norm, p_z_sim) indicating **the statistical significance of any spatial autocorrelation**.

You should report one of these p-values in addition to the Moran I statistic. I would avoid reporting *p_norm* unless you are confident that your sample originates from a population with a Gaussian distribution. The permutation test is more robust since it makes fewer distributional assumptions. See [geoda documentation](https://geodacenter.github.io/workbook/5a_global_auto/lab5a.html) by Luc Anselin:

[image: geoda documentation]